# Axios doesn't send header to server side controller

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-native, controller, axios

I am relatively new to React Native world. I've faced a problem while trying to send parameters from React Native to Spring Boot Controller. Even though the method on the controller is called, the parameters are always empty.

Here is my react code (with hardcoded values to send):

```
 login(user) {   
 return axios.get(API_URL + 'login',
 { email: 'test', password: 'test' })
 .then(response => {
 console.log('function called')
```

And here is contoller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> login(String email, String password) {

    return new ResponseEntity<>(userServiceImpl.getUserByEmail(email).get(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now, while debugging controller I see that the method is called, but it receives null.
I guess I am doing something wrong in frontend part, but can't find what could the issue.

Comment: Is axios.get, not meant to be `axios.get(URL, { params: { email: 'test', password: 'test' }})` (based on their docs) and then controller needs `@RequestParam("email") String email...`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use post instead of get or should try to send parameters in the link (ie. login/email/:email) or query (ie. login?email=test) instead of sending request body with get.You mustn't send password in url as parameter for the sake of security.So you should use post.